# Facebook Comments is giving "Warning: [URL] is unreachable." But Facebook Debugger is showing a Status 200 for the page. How do I fix this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I've searched all over for a solution to this, but can't find anyone else with the same problem. The Facebook Comments plugin is telling me: "Warning: http://www.runnersworld.com/fun/gear-review-old-yellow-jacket is unreachable." but when I look up that page in the Facebook Object Debugger, I get a Status 200 and no errors:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.runnersworld.com%2Ffun%2Fgear-review-old-yellow-jacket

(There is one warning, but it's about an image, and shouldn't be causing the unreachable error. I think it is unrelated.)

Every other forum thread that I found was solved by fixing the errors that appears on the Debugger console, but without any errors appearing there, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be fixing.

We tried matching the data-href to match the og:url (the only difference is a query string) but that didn't fix the problem and wiped out all of our existing comments, so we rolled it back.

Any ideas how we can fix this? It's not just this one article, but several articles throughout the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this problem was being caused by the Fetched URL and Canonical URL being different in Facebook's [Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.runnersworld.com%2Ffun%2Fgear-review-old-yellow-jacket). To resolve it, I copied the Canonical URL (http://www.runnersworld.com/fun/gear-review-old-yellow-jacket?page=single) into the Input URL box at the top, then clicked the "Fetch new scrape information" button. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the cache from facebook like this :

got to facebook debugger and post your URL with refresh param like this

http://www.runnersworld.com/fun/gear-review-old-yellow-jacket?referesh=true

Try this more than once until facebook remove the cache.

Comment: That didn't work, but it gave me an idea... I noticed that the canonical URL (http://www.runnersworld.com/fun/gear-review-old-yellow-jacket?page=single) was different than the fetch URL http://www.runnersworld.com/fun/gear-review-old-yellow-jacket), so I pasted the canonical URL into the Input URL field and clicked the "Fetch new scrape information" button. That worked.